# how to check current time is a multiple of five minutes in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, datetime

I want to know if the current time is a multiple of five. That means, I want to check if it is 8:30, 8:35, 8:40, .... is there any function in javascript or php that can do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
function isFivesMultiple(){
    return new Date().getMinutes() % 5 == 0
}
```

what about 19:00?

Comment: *what about 19:00* 0 is multiple of 5 as well, 5 * 0 = 0.

Comment: I know :) Just wanted to know Op's expectation

Comment: I don't code in Javascript/PHP, but I had a similar question in Go, and this answer was helpful, so thanks for that. However, besides checking `minutes % 5`, I had to also confirm that seconds, milliseconds & microseconds are exactly zero as well (because 19:00:01 isn't a multiple of five minutes).

Answer (score 3):

in php it is:

```
if(date('i')%5==0){
    echo "the current date is a multiple of 5";
}
```

Comment: `if(date('i')%5==0){` for minutes, not `m`, as OP is asking about time

Comment: Your code will work properly in January, May, October, ... :)

Comment: I just changed it to `i` as well.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, get the current minutes (`Date.getMinutes()`) and check it is a multiple of 5 using the modulo (`%`) operator;

```
var date = new Date(2013,3,9,8,30)
alert(date.getMinutes() % 5 == 0); // alerts "true"

var date2 = new Date(2013,3,9,8,32)
alert(date2.getMinutes() % 5 == 0);  // alerts "false"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$now=time();
$minute=date('i',$now);
if($minute>0)
{
    if($minute%5==0)
        echo 'true'.date('H:i',$now);
    else
        echo 'false'.date('H:i',$now);
}
else
{
    echo 'true'.date('H:i',$now);
}
?>
```